# Popup.js issue in IE9 only

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Having trouble with my site and IE9, if i change the compatibility mode to anything other than IE 9 standard my login popup works however when in IE9 standard which is the default it does not work. I think the best way to look at this is to try it yourself. [My Site](http://aliahealthcare.com/NEWHOME.php)

I get this error when i debug it:

`SCRIPT5009: 'Draggable' is undefined 
popup.js, line 77 character 9`

anyone familiar with popup.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO you have a different script running another script using jQuery before popup.js?

Try removing the other script if so, and see if this popup.js is adversely affected.

Comment: well the only thing is prototype.js and that is needed for my popup to work. However this is no issue in any other browser including anything but IE9 standard.

Comment: try renaming prototype.js and rereferncing it. IE9 is buggy as hell.